# Understanding memcpy

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

```
int a = 10;
int* pA = &a;
long long b = 200;
long long* pB = &b;

memcpy (pB,pA,4);
memcpy (pB+1,pA,4);

cout<<"I'm a memcpy!: "<<*(pB)<<endl;
```

I'm doing some tests with memcpy to teach myself how memory works.  What I am trying to do is make b = to "1010".  I can copy the value from a to b, but then I try to offset the memory by 1 byte and write another 10 but it doesn't work it only outputs "10".

What would I need to do to get a value of 1010?

Comment: `pB+1` increments it by more than 1 byte: `sizeof(long long)` bytes to be exact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few problems with your code as it stands:

- You copy 4 bytes, but the destination is type `int`.  Since `int` is not guaranteed to be any particular size, you need to make sure that it is at least 4 bytes long before you do that sort of `memcpy`.
- `memcpy` works on the byte level, but integers are a series of bytes.  Depending on your target architecture, the bytes within an integer may be arranged differently (big-endian, little-endian, etc).  Using `memcpy` on integers may or may not do what you expect.  It's best to use byte arrays when learning how `memcpy` and friends work.
- Your second `memcpy` uses `pB+1` as the target.  This doesn't advance the pointer one byte, it advances it by `sizeof(*pB)` bytes.  In this case, that leaves it pointing to an invalid address (past the end of the variable).  This call to `memcpy` will corrupt random memory, which can crash your program or cause unpredictable results.

Comment: Cool I learned a lot.  I do have one question though, you say that an int isnt' garanteed to take up 4bytes...I thought it was?  Is 4bytes just the limit that it can take up?  When I create an int and intilize it to a value does it only use the number of bits, or bytes nesccary?

Comment: Int size is machine and compiler dependent.  I can't think of a modern compiler/CPU that don't have 4-byte ints, but I can think of lots of old ones.  It is likely that future machines will have bigger ints.  When we get 128-bit machines, ints will probably be 64 bits (8-bytes).

Comment: @user1372122- The basic types `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` don't have standardized sizes.  `int` has a *fixed* size, but that fixed size varies from platform to platform (for example between x86 and MIPS CPUs, or between 32-bit and 64-bit OSes).  There *are* datatypes, however, that are guaranteed to have specific sizes.  They have names like `uint32_t` and `int16_t` (for a 32-bit unsigned integer and 16-bit signed integer, respectively) and they come from `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `memcpy()` is designed for what you want.  In general, you would use `memcpy()` to copy one or more whole objects (where an object might be an int, a char, a long long, etc.)

```
    int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int b[3];
    int c[5] = { 0 };

    ::memcpy(b, a, 3 * sizeof(int));   // b is { 1, 2, 3 }
    ::memcpy(c+2, b, 3 * sizeof(int)); // c is { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3 }
```

c+2 is not "c + 2 bytes".  It is "c + 2 ints" (8 bytes on a Win32/x86 system).

You *can* access the individual bytes by casting to a char or unsigned char pointer, but I don't recommend that unless you really understand what you're doing as there are many pitfalls.

```
    unsigned x = 0;
    unsigned char *px = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&x);

    px[0] = 0xFF;
    px[2] = 0xAA;
```

One of the dangers here is that you are assuming knowledge about how the computer stores an integer.  On an x86 system, x will be 0x00AA00FF but on a Sun Sparc system it will be 0xFF00AA00.

if you need to set parts of an integer it is often better to use "or" and "shift".

```
    x = (0xFF<<24) | (0xAA<<8);
```

will give you 0xFF00AA00 on any architecture.
0xFF<<24 shifts the value 0xFF by 24 bits to the left, making 0xFF000000.
0xAA<<8  shifts the value 0xAA by 8 bits to the left, making 0x0000AA00.

We "or" them together, giving 0xFF00AA00.

Answer (score 1):

Look into pointer arithmetic: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html . Adding a value to a pointer actually incrememnts by that many units of whatever size you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

pB is of type long long*, so adding 1 to it will give the address to the next set of eight bytes following variable b.   You have pB[0] being the variable b, but pB[1] (equivalent to pB+1) point to undefined memory.  Writing to it will likely cause a crash.

Replace

```
long long b;
```

with

```
long long b[2];
```

(use whatever initial values you like)

Your cout will need to be fed both b[0] and b[1].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy "10" to the bytes afterward and get "1010", you want to copy the string.  This is really the job of `strcat()` rather than `memcpy()`, but here is a way you could do it with `memcpy()`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  constexpr char src[] = "10";
  constexpr size_t n = sizeof(src) - 1; // Don’t count the terminator.
  char dest[2*n+1] = {'\0'}; // Will hold: {'1','0','1','0','\0'}

  static_assert( sizeof(dest) > 2*n, "" ); // Always check array bounds in C++!

  memcpy( dest, src, n );
  memcpy( dest + n, src, n );

  puts(dest);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In particular, observe that the destination is an array of bytes long enough to hold both copies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation score >= 50, so I can't post the comment, even as the original author of the commented post -> which is simply stupid from my point of view...

So, here's my answer for the comment posted by user207421:

1. SIMD instructions are implemented in every CPU used in PCs in the last 20 years (at least), so unless You're using some *very* old CPU, your claim regarding "recent enough" CPUs is basically invalid.
2. See point 2 in my post above: "the fastest architecture-dependant methods" means that f.e. on an 8-bit AVR, the "movw" instruction can be (and it is) used to implement fast memcpy-like functions, because it works similarly to SIMD on x86: it can copy 2 8-bit CPU words in a single cycle.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

> memcpy works on the byte level, but integers are a series of bytes.

WRONG explanation.

The above answer would be more or less true for a `strcpy()`, but it's entirely wrong in case of `memcpy()`, because all the `mem_xxx()` functions are using SIMD instructions to speed-up the operations.

If the `memcpy()` function would be based on byte-by-byte copying, it would be deadly slow...

Basically, all of the `mem_xxx` functions are implemented like this:

1. If the source and/or destination pointers are unaligned, then those functions are aligning the pointers by first processing the unaligned/odd memory chunks.
2. Next, the fastest architecture-dependant methods are used to process the aligned memory area.
3. Finally, the remaining unaligned/odd bytes are processed.

I suggest to actually *read* the code before posting incorrect answers.

Comment: You appear to be commenting on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11025101/207421). You should make that clear. Your own answer assumes an x86 recent enough to have SIMD instructions.